# How to have parent data be updated by child component with multiple values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Code below.

I think I'm missing a crucial piece here. I've been through the docs and watched the entire vue2 step by step. Everything is making sense so far but I'm stuck on what seems to be a core piece. Any help would be appreciated. If this is totally wrong, please let me know, I'm not married to any of this stuff.

*Desired functionality*: There is an `order` Vue instance and it has `line items`.

On `order.mounted()` we hit an api endpoint for the order's data, including possible existing line items. If there are existing line items, we set that order data (`this.lineitems = request.body.lineitems` or similar). This part works fine and I can get the order total since the orders' line items are up to date at this point.

Each line item is an editable form with a quantity  and a product .  If I change the quantity or product of any line item, I want the child line-item component to notify the parent component that it changed, then the parent will update its own lineitems data array with the new value, and preform a POST request with all current line item data so the server side can calculate the new line item totals (many specials, discounts, etc). This will return a full replacement array for the order's line item data, which in turn would passed down to the line items to re-render.

Problems:

1. The line-items components "update..." methods are feeling obviously wrong, but my biggest issue is understanding how to get the parent to update its own line items data array with the new data. for instance

​

```
lineitems = [
  {id: 1000, quantity: 3, product: 555, total: 30.00}, 
  {id: 1001, quantity: 2, product: 777, total: 10.00}
]
```

If the second line item is changed to quantity 1, how do I get the parent's lineitems data to change to this? My main problem is that I don't know how the parent is suppose to know which of its own lineitems data array need to be modified, and how to grab the data from the changed child. I assume it came in via an event, via emit, but do I now need to pass around the primary key everywhere so I can do loops and compare? What if its a new line item and there is no primary key yet?

2. Mentioned above, I'm using the existing line item's DB primary key as the v-for key. What if I need a "new lineitem" that appends a blank lineitem below the existing ones, or if its a new order with no primary keys. How is this normally handled.
3. Is there a best practice to use for props instead of my "initial..." style? I assume just using $emit directly on the `v-on`, but I'm not sure how to get the relevant information to get passed that way.

This seems like the exact task that VueJS is suited for and I just feel like I keep chasing my tail in the wrong direction. Thanks for the help!

**LineItem**

```
Vue.component('line-item', {
    props: ["initialQuantity", "initialProduct", "total"],
    data () {
        return {
            // There are more but limiting for example
            quantity: initialQuantity,
            product: initialProduct,
            productOptions = [
                { id: 333, text: "Product A"},
                { id: 555, text: "Product B"},
                { id: 777, text: "Product C"},
            ]
        }
    },
    updateQuantity(event) {
        item = {
            quantity: event.target.value,
            product: this.product
        }
        this.$emit('update-item', item)
    },
    updateProduct(event) {
        item = {
            quantity: this.quantity,
            product: event.target.value
        }
        this.$emit('update-item', item)
    }
    template: `
        <input :value="quantity" type="number" @input="updateQuantity">

        <select :value="product" @input="updateProduct">
            <option v-for="option in productOptions" v-bind:value="option.id"> {{ option.text }} </option>
        </select>

        Line Item Price: {{ total }}
        <hr />
    `
})
```

**Order/App**

```
var order = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        orderPK: orderPK,
        lineitems: []
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchLineItems()
    },
    computed: {
        total() {
            // This should sum the line items, like (li.total for li in this.lineitems)
            return 0.0
    },
    methods: {
        updateOrder(item) {
            // First, somehow update this.lineitems with the passed in item, then
            fetch(`domain.com/orders/${this.orderPK}/calculate`, this.lineitems)
                .then(resp => resp.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.lineitems = data.lineitems;
                })
        },
        fetchLineItems() {
            fetch(`domain.com/api/orders/${this.orderPK}`)
                .then(resp => resp.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.lineitems = data.lineitems;
                })
        },
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <h2 id="total">Order total: {{ total }}</h2>

            <line-item v-for="item in lineitems"
                @update-item="updateOrder"
                :key="item.id"
                :quantity="item.quantity"
                :product="item.product"
                :total="item.total"
                ></line-item>
        </div>
    `
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of problems in your *attempt* that would prevent it from displaying anything at all i.e.

1. `quantity: initialQuantity`, - surely you meant `quantity: this.initialQuantity`, ... etc for all the other such data
2. missing `}` for computed total
3. your `line-item` template is invalid - you have multiple "root" elements

And then there's some minor issues:

1. you want the `@change` handler for the select, not `@input`, if your code ran, you'd see the difference,
2. Similarly you want `@change` for input otherwise you'll be making fetch requests to change the items every keystroke, probably not what you'd want

So, despite all that, I've produced some working code that does all you need - mainly for my own "learning" though, to be fair :p

```js
// ******** some dummy data and functions to emulate fetches
const products = [
    { id: 333, text: "Product A", unitPrice: 10},
    { id: 555, text: "Product B", unitPrice: 11},
    { id: 777, text: "Product C", unitPrice: 12},
];

let dummy = [
    {id: 1, quantity:2, product: 333, total: 20},
    {id: 2, quantity:3, product: 777, total: 36},
];

const getLineItems = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, JSON.stringify({lineitems: dummy})));
const update = items => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        dummy = JSON.parse(items);
        dummy.forEach(item => 
            item.total = parseFloat(
                (
                    item.quantity * 
                    (products.find(p => p.id === item.product) || {unitPrice: 0}).unitPrice *
                    (item.quantity > 4 ? 0.9 : 1.0)
                ).toFixed(2)
            )
        );
        let res = JSON.stringify({lineitems: dummy});
        resolve(res);
    }, 50));
}

//********* lineItem component
Vue.component('line-item', {
    props: ["value"],
    data () {
        return {
            productOptions: [
                { id: 333, text: "Product A"},
                { id: 555, text: "Product B"},
                { id: 777, text: "Product C"},
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        doupdate() {
            this.$emit('update-item', this.value.product);
        }
    },
    template: `
        <p>
            <input v-model="value.quantity" type="number" @change="doupdate()"/>

            <select v-model="value.product" @change="doupdate()">
                <option v-for="option in productOptions" v-bind:value="option.id"> {{ option.text }} </option>
            </select>

            Line Item Price: {{ '$' + value.total.toFixed(2) }}
        </p>
    `
})

//********* Order/App
const orderPK = '';
var order = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        orderPK: orderPK,
        lineitems: []
    },
    mounted() {
        // initial load
        this.fetchLineItems();
    },
    computed: {
        carttotal() {
            return this.lineitems.reduce((a, {total}) => a + total, 0)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateOrder(productCode) {
            // only call update if the updated item has a product code
            if (productCode) {
                // real code would be
                // fetch(`domain.com/orders/${this.orderPK}/calculate`, this.lineitems).then(resp => resp.json())
                // dummy code is
                update(JSON.stringify(this.lineitems)).then(data => JSON.parse(data))
                
                .then(data => this.lineitems = data.lineitems);
            }
        },
        fetchLineItems() {

            // real code would be
            //fetch(`domain.com/api/orders/${this.orderPK}`).then(resp => resp.json())
            // dummy code is
            getLineItems().then(data => JSON.parse(data))
            
            .then(data => this.lineitems = data.lineitems);
            
        },
        addLine() {
            this.lineitems.push({
                id: Math.max([this.lineitems.map(({id}) => id)]) + 1, 
                quantity:0, 
                product: 0, 
                total: 0
            });
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <h2 id="total">Order: {{lineitems.length}} items, total: {{'$'+carttotal.toFixed(2)}}</h2>

            <line-item v-for="(item, index) in lineitems"
                :key="item.id"
                v-model="lineitems[index]"
                @update-item="updateOrder"
            />
            <button @click="addLine()">
                Add item
            </button>
        </div>
    `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
        <div id="app">
        </div>
```

note: there may be some *inefficient* code in there, please don't judge too harshly, I've only been using vuejs for a week

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. All this code was copy/pasted from my actual code, in order to just simplify the concepts. 1, 2 and 3 were just issues with the copy/paste/tweak cycle. I was using @input for the select, because I'm actually using vue-multiselect, and simplified it for this example. Also for quantity, I actually do want it to update on each change since you can increment and decrement with the arrows. -- For the specifics though, you have a `doupdate()` method, but its only references product and not quantity. Again thanks for the time, I shouldve ensured the code worked

Comment: fair enough then - hope the code helps anyway - dec/inc on the arrows fires a change event anyway :p - just think that if you want to order 20 of something and use the keyboard, you'd be updating twice for no reason

Comment: Is there a difference between  `v-model="lineitems[index]"` and just `v-model="item"` in your example above?

Comment: the `doupdate` sends the product id so that there's no update if the product id is 0 - i.e. for a new item, the product id is zero until you select a product, there's no point updating without a product

Comment: the difference is that you can't use `item` in the `v-for` - try changing it, look in the console, you'll see the issue

Comment: Then how does the parent get informed of the new quantity? Just via the `v-model="lineitems[index]"`?

Comment: the parent gets "informed" of the new quantity, because the children are bound to them ... `v-model="value.quantity"` and `v-model="value.product"`

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I get it now! Big thank you, I'm gonna dive back in.

Comment: Finally! I've been beating my head against a wall for two days on this. I finally go it, thanks to you. It was the v-model usage along with the slicing with the index. I hadn't seen that before. You've made my weekend. Thanks!